# Any GUI for IronPython application

Tags: user-interface, ironpython

Hello i want to design a GUI for IronPython script.
Can someone suggest me which is the best and easiest to use. I would like to run a script when one press a button and displays a output in textbox.

Comment: Have you looked at IronPython + WPF? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Simon Opelt I am using IronPython 2.7 for writting script and to design a GUI itself in ironPython is cumbersome process. so if you have any idea, could you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"One of the easiest ways (TM)"* to create simple GUIs in [IronPython](http://www.ironpython.net) is using [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms754130.aspx), [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) and [Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://pytools.codeplex.com/).

A simple GUI like asked (containing buttons, text boxes etc.) can be created using a [visual designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514528(v=vs.100).aspx) and the functions doing the work can be created and wired with tool support (like generation or auto completion).

[Jeff Hardy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129592) created [a set of samples](https://github.com/jdhardy/IronPythonSamples) which also contains a [pure python WPF app](https://github.com/jdhardy/IronPythonSamples/tree/master/PyWpfSample) which shows (in about 100 lines of code and markup) what is required for your use-case.

Comment: beware of the fact that the versions of Python Tools For VS from version 2.0 and higher require .NET 4.5 which doesn't run on Windows XP